# Can I still use pronominal verbs without having a subject to which they refer?

Tags: infinitif, verbes-pronominaux

I'm so confused about how to write this sentence without 'la personne' in it:

> Le sport aide la personne à bien se concentrer.

I want to remove 'la personne' so should I also remove 'se'? Cause se  is referring to 'la personne'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Le sport aide à bien se concentrer.

Works, as well as:

> Le sport aide à la concentration.